# Neo4j - How to Load dumped neo4j database in community version

Tags: neo4j

I have "dump"ed one Neo4j database from Neo4j Desktop edition, and trying to load that database in a community edition.

While dumping I have used the following:

```
neo4j-admin dump --to=E:\DumpDB
```

But while importing it in community edition I could not run the following command:

```
neo4j-admin load --from=<archive-path> --database=<database>
```

Because I couldn't find any neo4j-admin in community edition.

Please any advice on how to import it in community edition would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a recent version (say, 3.1+) of the neo4j Community Edition, its installation folder should have a `bin` subfolder that contains the `neo4j-admin` tool.